# PHP, highlight part of keyword instead of the whole word

Tags: php, keyword

I have a piece of code that is highlighting a keyword in a search function. Instead of that i would like to be able to highlight the keyword even if it is part of a word of the text.
For example if i search for "el" and finds the word "hello", to be shown like h**el**lo .

Here is the code :

```
function highlight_keywords($content, $keywords) {

    if (!is_array($keywords)) {
    $keywords = explode(' ', $keywords);
    }
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    if (trim($keyword) !== '') {
        $content = preg_replace('/\b(' . preg_quote($keyword) . ')\b/i',     '<span>\1</span>', $content);
    }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Take out the `\b` word delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($keyword) . ')/is','<span>$1</span>', $content);
```

Comment: Great! Works! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier, you could just use `str_replace()`

```
$keywords = array('el');
$string = 'hello world';

foreach($keywords as $keyword){
    $string = str_ireplace($keyword, '<b>' . $keyword . '</b>', $string);
}

// $string is now: h<b>el</b>lo world
```

Comment: The only problem would be if the word is with upper case letters and you are replacing it with lower case letters

Comment: in that case, just use `str_ireplace()`, the case insensitive version.

Comment: sorry probably i didn't explain that right I meant that this echo str_ireplace('el', '<span>el</span>', 'HELLO'); produces this: H<span>el</span>LO (HelLO)

Comment: +1 @lexmihaylov I see what you mean. Unfortunately that would be a limitation of using `str_replace()` :(